# Getting at least one value from many select boxes involved in one form PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation, select

My code has many select boxes where they are generated dynamically with different values through while loop PHP. All of them involved in one form with one submit button regardless the number of boxes(I know how to get their values separately).

What I would like to do is, force the user to choose a value at least of one of them before continuing to the next page.

```
<?php
$items = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table where column='$var'" ) or die  ('mysql_error');
echo '<form action="myform.php" method="post">';
while ($item = mysql_fetch_array($items))
     {
      $id = $item ['id'];
      $number = $item ['number'];
      echo '<select name="number['.$id.']" class="number234">';
      echo '<option value="">0</option>';
      for ($i = 1; $i <= $number; $i++)
          {
          echo '<option value="'.$i.'">' . $i . '</option>' . "\n";
          }               
      echo '</select>';
     }
    echo '<input type="submit" class="link"  name="book" value="book" />';
 echo '</form>';
 ?>
```

I have searched a lot about this and I’ve just found a solution which I still can not apply to my code. As it seems I need to involve PHP code into the javascript and I am not clever enough to do this.
Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/rj5Gw/

Comment: you could disable the button until an option has been selected?

Comment: or check on Submit if at least one is selected - if not, show a message saying something like "Please select at least one value"

Comment: @ElDoRado1239 how will be the full code then?

Comment: Added a solution I would suggest below.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming this is what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/6hhnw9bd/1/

```
$("#mybutton").click(function(e){
    var flag = 0;
    $(".selectgroup").each(function(){
     if($(this).val() != ""){
            flag = 1;
     }
    });
    if(flag == 1){
     alert("Valid");
    } else {
     alert("Select an option");
     e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly with me. But I sill have a small issue. After submitting the form with no selected value and showing the alert of "Select an option". The form action is still taking place after pressing ok. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Check my solution below which prevents this, or cancel the event's propagation in the part where you alert Select an option - event.stopPropagation();

Comment: Yeah my bad. It's been a while since I did anything with jquery. 
Anyways, here's the updated code http://jsfiddle.net/6hhnw9bd/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `onbeforeupload` event to check if an option is selected or not

```js
var formSubmitting = false;
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.myform').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
      formSubmitting = true;
    });
    $('.myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            Input1: {
                require_from_group: [1, ".selectgroup"]
            },
            Input2: {
                require_from_group: [1, ".selectgroup"]
            }
        },
        groups: {
            group: "Input1 Input2"
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
            return false; // for demo
        }
    });

});

 $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
  if (formSubmitting) {
    return undefined;
  }
  if($('#input1').val() == '' && $('#input2').val() == '' ){
    return "Select an option";
  } 
 });
```

```css
#docs {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form class="myform">
    <select name="Input1" id="input1" class="selectgroup">
        <option value="">please select...</option>
        <option value="DO0" opt_numAdults="2" opt_numChilds="0">0</option>
        <option value="DO1" opt_numAdults="2" opt_numChilds="0">1</option>
        <option value="DO2" opt_numAdults="2" opt_numChilds="0">2</option>
        <option value="DO3" opt_numAdults="2" opt_numChilds="0">3</option>
        <option value="DO4" opt_numAdults="2" opt_numChilds="0">4</option>
        <option value="DO5" opt_numAdults="2" opt_numChilds="0">5</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <select name="Input2" id="input2"  class="selectgroup">
        <option value="">please select...</option>
        <option value="FP0" opt_numAdults="2" opt_numChilds="1">0</option>
        <option value="FP1" opt_numAdults="2" opt_numChilds="1">1</option>
        <option value="FP2" opt_numAdults="2" opt_numChilds="1">2</option>
        <option value="FP3" opt_numAdults="2" opt_numChilds="1">3</option>
        <option value="FP4" opt_numAdults="2" opt_numChilds="1">4</option>
        <option value="FP5" opt_numAdults="2" opt_numChilds="1">5</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <button type="submit" id="mybutton">Go</button>
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note most browsers don't support custom message for `onbeforeunload`
For more information https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Answer (score 0):

Pretty basic, but it should work. First a function to check if at least one of the Selects has a value, then a fake Submit button that simulates pressing the real hidden Submit button only of the check goes through.

Oh, right, and all the Selects should have one option with value "".

```
function anythingSelected(){
 var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
 for(var i=0;i<selects.length;i++) if(selects[i].value != "") return true;
 return false;
}
function submitForm(){
 if(anythingSelected()) document.getElementById('submitButton').click();
 else alert('Select something please!');
}

...

<input type="submit" id="submitButton" hidden />
<input type="button" onclick="submitForm();" value="Send"/>
```

Example :

```js
function anythingSelected(){
 var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
 for(var i=0;i<selects.length;i++) if(selects[i].value != "") return true;
 return false;
}
function submitForm(){
 if(anythingSelected()) document.getElementById('submitButton').click();
 else alert('Select something please!');
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
 select{ width: 100px; }
</style>
<script>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="test.php">
<select><option value=""></option><option value="A">A</option></select>
<select><option value=""></option><option value="A">A</option></select>
<select><option value=""></option><option value="A">A</option></select>
<select><option value=""></option><option value="A">A</option></select>
<select><option value=""></option><option value="A">A</option></select>
<input type="submit" id="submitButton" hidden />
<input type="button" onclick="submitForm();" value="Send"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```